# C# WPF Read Listbox item without System.Windows.Controls

Tags: c#, wpf

When I try to read ListBox items to XML file İ read the name but with System.Windows.Controls always add in listbox items. How can I get the name?

```
private void Window_Closed(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        List<string> dosyaAdlari = new List<string>();

        for (int i = 0; i < listbox1.Items.Count; i++)
        {
            dosyaAdlari.Add(listbox1.Items[i].ToString());
        }

        using (System.IO.StreamWriter yazici = new System.IO.StreamWriter(dosyaYolu))
        {
            XmlSerializer serilestirici = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<string>));
            serilestirici.Serialize(yazici, dosyaAdlari);
        }
    }

    private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            List<string> dosyaİsimleri = new List<string>();

            using (StreamReader yazici = new StreamReader(dosyaYolu))
            {
                XmlSerializer deSerilestirici = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<string>));
                dosyaİsimleri = (List<string>)deSerilestirici.Deserialize(yazici);

            }
            for (int i = 0; i < dosyaİsimleri.Count; i++)
            {
                listbox1.Items.Add(dosyaİsimleri[i]);
            }
        }
            catch
            {
            }
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`ListBox.Items` is `ItemCollection` type, so when you use `ListBox.Items[0]` you get `Item` and `ToString()` method gives you full name of type. What you need is `ListBox.ItemsSource[0]`, that will give you value of that item, it represents object like `string` or `int` that is bound to particular `ListBox item`.